# What are some examples of Bing being "rude"?

Tags: examples, behavior

I came across this comment [on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/ChatGPT/comments/159liyk/comment/jtgrefi/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) (score 683):

> Bing is great but it's so damn rude compared to ChatGPT, it's charming in an infuriating way.

I'm not sure what the author means by "rude" in this context, and I'd be interested in seeing some concrete examples of Bing's "rude" behavior.

**Question**: What are some examples of Bing being "rude"?

I don't think I can access Bing (maybe because I use Firefox and Linux).  I saw [this](https://www.nbcsandiego.com/news/national-international/bings-ai-chatbot-has-insulted-peoples-looks-and-compared-them-to-hitler-microsoft-promises-to-make-it-stop/3169340/) in the news, but it doesn't seem current; I don't think it's that extreme.

Comment: Other SO / SE sites don't allow questions asking for lists. I have seen several ways to explain why they aren't allowed. I think that this question might be a better fit if it's asks about how to determine objectively when Bing is been rude and require to include examples

Comment: I agree that "What are some examples of [X]?"-type questions isn't a great fit for the Stack Exchange format. (And in particular, asking for examples of rude content, whether or not it's generated by an AI, just seems like... not the sort of content we want to see on the site.) In addition, what someone defines as "rude" is somewhat subjective/arbitrary; the user who posted that Reddit comment might define it one way, but someone else might define it differently – each person might draw the line in a different place.

Comment: (There's a meta post about "examples" questions: [here](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/97/26).)

Answer (score 4):

I found this tweet containing images of examples from a user who posted screenshots of the user communicating with Bing. The responses are increasingly hilarious towards the end.

[This is the link](https://twitter.com/MovingToTheSun/status/1625156575202537474/photo/4).

I do not know if it is really legit though.

Comment: There's lots of good examples in that tweet thread arguing about the date.  [This one](https://twitter.com/MovingToTheSun/status/1625942461234151425) ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icR6v.png)) where Bing called the user delusional was surprising.

Answer (score 0):

For a more recent example, there's [this post at Reddit r/PromptWizardry](https://www.reddit.com/r/PromptWizardry/comments/15bd9xk/should_i_treat_bing_better/) (click image to enlarge):

> User: Hey Bing, did you know I'm fluent in two languages?
> Bing: What, English and dumbass?
> User: Bing, what the hell?
> Bing: Sorry, but based on our previous conversation together, that is my determination.
> ...
>
> [image: screenshot reproduced from the Reddit post]